# Getting Infinite Loop For Certain Inputs

Tags: python, while-loop, infinite-loop, binary-search

Working on an exercise using binary search to arrive at an answer to a credit card payment problem. I thought I had rock solid (albeit I'm sure elementary) code, that works for the example inputs, however the check is returning an infinite loop. I've tried about 20 different inputs for Balance, and all came back correct, until plugging in Balance = 2000, then it threw the infinite loop. I cannot figure out why. Any help is greatly appreciated Here is my code:

```
balance = 2000
annualInterestRate = .18
monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 12.0
lower_bound = balance / 12.0
upper_bound = (balance * (1 + monthlyInterestRate) ** 12) / 12.0
monthly_payment = (lower_bound + upper_bound) / 2.0
new_balance = balance

while new_balance != 0:
    monthly_payment = (lower_bound + upper_bound) / 2.0
    new_balance = balance
    month = 0

    while month < 12 and new_balance != 0:

        month += 1
        new_balance = new_balance - monthly_payment
        new_balance = new_balance + (new_balance * monthlyInterestRate)
        new_balance = round(new_balance,2)

    if new_balance < 0:
        upper_bound = monthly_payment

    else:
        lower_bound = monthly_payment 


print "Lowest Payment:", round(monthly_payment,2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rounding error: new_balance ends up 0.01. You probably want to check that lower_bound and upper_bound are still not equal in the `while` condition.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that the new_balance can become negative. If that is the case, then it will never fall out ot the main loop. put in a debug test

```
if new_balance < 0:
  raise ValueError
```

You can put in a print in the except or just use that to check. Alternatively, change the while to

```
while new_balance > 0:
```

Additionally, check that new_balance is not < .01 before the round. In fact, I would never allow a round up, but would always round down.

Also after having run a quick check, I saw a print out of new_balance after the round giving results of

```
.01
1846.64
1690.98
```

and the loop continues down to .01 again and around.